# ASP .NET MVC Onion Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, onion-architecture

I'm developing an application following this architecture:

1. Core project (Domain entities, Repositories interfaces)
2. Infrastructure project (Database operation, Repository implementation, EF)
3. Test project (Unit Test project)
4. Web project (MVC project)

From this tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/step-by-step-implementing-onion-architecture-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

I want to decouple my project and follow a "standard architecture". I have a few question:

1) I want to add a bussines layer, should i add a project like SolutionName.Services?

2) If i add the business layer, I need to use dependency injection to call the repositories in the business layer?

2.1) If my CRUD operation does not need business logic, the service (business layer) should only call the method on the repository? (I have models with business logic and models without business logic)

3) In the project, I need to read files and process the data based on the needs of the user, this should go in the business layer?

Comment: If it's just CRUD you don't need a service or repository. Stop creating fluff and abusing patterns.

Comment: @Phill reading files and processing the data based on the needs of the user does not count as business logic?

Comment: If you don't have business logic on the data, why would you even care to add a business layer which is meant for business logic on data? As Phill said, stop abusing patterns.

Comment: Do you ever *need* a service/repository pattern? They are usually a good idea, in my experience.  Business logic could always be added in the future.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I have business logic in one model

Comment: Business logic should go in the center, inside the domain. You would pass in your dependencies to the domain model. However, if you just have CRUD evrywhere else you probably dont need a domain model at all right now, just keep things simple